# How a ViewController instance links to the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm getting started with Xcode, Swift, etc. for iOS development and I was wondering how exactly an instance of my `ViewController` class is linked to my storyboard.  Here's my MRE:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("The button was pressed")
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that somewhere in the background my app will instantiate `ViewController` and its various methods such as `buttonPressed` will be called.  However, if I were to hypothetically create two separate instances of my class and the user pressed the button, would both instances get their `buttonPressed` method called?  I'd test this myself but I don't yet know enough about how all of this works.

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard, check **the identity inspector**, the ViewController will be linked with storyboard when you set a class name there, check the photo below to understand

[image]

Whenever the ViewController is linked with any scene in the storyboard, you can insert action or outlet into that view controller

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I've already created my `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction`.  What I'm wondering is how they will interact if two instances of `ViewController` are instantiated.

Comment: You would typically only have one instance of a view controller visible at a time. If you did have two instances visible then each button would interact with its own instance if the view controller

Comment: Correctly @Paulw11

Comment: So, the second instance would create a second "screen" complete with a second button?

Comment: Yes when you create like let viewcontroller = ViewController() // this is a screen

Comment: Ah, got it!  @Paulw11, if you'd like to post that as an answer...